# I know how to build a functional store in React, if I want to deploy it online to let sellers enter their own products, how can I do this, dashboard?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I know how to build a functional store and a shopping card in React, if I want to deploy it online to let sellers enter their own products and titles and description, how can I do this, I think it will be something like a dashboard?

I know how to build a functional store and a shopping card in React, if I want to deploy it online to let sellers enter their own products and titles and desCRIPTION

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.